# How can I efficiently extract sub-images from a batch of images with each sub-image at a different location?

Tags: image, tensorflow, image-processing, attention-model

I need to extract (m x m) sub-images from a batch of (n x n) images, where:

images.shape = (batch, n, n, n_channels),
sub-images.shape = (batch, m, m, n_channels),

and where each sub-image is in a different location for each image in the batch. Seems like the closest routine there is for this is:  **tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box()**, but this uses the same cropping parameters for all images in the batch. Is there a simple way to do this? I can always resort to gather_nd() but that is very cumbersome.

Comment: You can do it quite simply outside of tensor flow in the shell with **GNU Parallel** and **ImageMagick** to get them all done in parallel - all you need is a list of the filenames and the matching coordinates in a text file.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. However, the problem here though is that the location of successive sub-images depend on Tensorflow variables.